# lazy image loading NOT IN listview

Tags: android

I have a list of data which I am showing in linearlayout. I am not using ListView as I dont want scrollbar, I want all my data visible at once. I am already processing using AsyncTask but now I want to fetch the images also. I want 1st AsynTask to complete its task and call another AsyncTask to load the images, but when I trying to call imageloader asyncTask from 1st asyncTask I  get
10-21 17:55:47.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(280): java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException

Can anyone help ???

Answer (score 1):

This exception is usually thrown when you are trying to run too many AsyncTasks at once. In  your case it would probably be better if you used your own ThreadPool (java.util.concurrent offers many classes to make it easy.)